# How to undo bzr add

Tags: bazaar

Sometimes I type `bzr add` and don't notice that I am not in the root of the branch but an ignored sub-folder. This then adds all files in that folders - often it is a build folder, with lots of files. Hence the question: how to undo a `bzr add`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is built-in way without need of xargs: `bzr remove --new --keep`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is shamelessly stolen from [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/132154) to make it more accessible (to me as well).

This will undo an erroneous `bzr add`:

`bzr added -0 | xargs -0 bzr rm --keep`